# Doctrine 2 DQL - nest expressions and functions in the QueryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, dql, query-builder

I have found [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) module that has implement some useful MySQL functions. But I think my problem is a general one. How would you pass another mysql expression as a parameter into a function?

If I had 2 columns `updated_at` which is a `DATETIME` and `lifespan` which is an `INT` and I wanted to query whether the lifetime of an entity had expired, I could do this;

```
WHERE 0 > TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECONDS, NOW(), e.updated_at + INTERVAL e.lifespan SECOND)
```

IN the QueryBuilder it's something like this.

```
$qb->andWhere('0 > TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECONDS, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), e.updated_at + INTERVAL e.lifespan SECOND)');
```

But the parser doesn't like `+ INTERVAL e.lifespan SECOND` because it expects the Close Parenthesis instead of a plus sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I can use the DateAdd class from the [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) module.

`TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), DATEADD(e.updated_at, INTERVAL e.lifespan SECOND))`